# How to add array into a matrix in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I just want to know how can i add

```
var arr_bck = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows_bck.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < rows_bck[i].length; j++) {
        if (rows_bck[i][j] == null) {
            rows_bck[i][j] = 0;
            sum += rows_bck[i][j];
        } else {
            sum += rows_bck[i][j];
        }
    }
    arr_bck.push(sum);
}
into:

var rows_bck = _.chain(newarrAots).groupBy(function (item) { return item.date; }).map(function (group, key) {

    var result = [key];
    _.each(group, function (item) {
        result[_.indexOf(header, item.teamName, arr_bck)] = item.aots_bck_cnt;
    });
    return result;

}).value();
```

i mean add arr_bck as new value in rows_bck matrix. Values in matrix are like this:

"02/11", 0, 0, 0, 0

"02/12", 193, 233, 212, 307

"02/13", 203, 264, 293, 227

and i want values like:

"02/11", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

"02/12", 193, 233, 212, 307, 945

"02/13", 203, 264, 293, 227, 987

last values are sum of the int numbers in each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need according to your question.
Just check the output of the snippet by running it :p

```js
var rows_bck=
[
["02/11", 0, 0, 0, 0],
["02/12", 193, 233, 212, 307],
["02/13", 203, 264, 293, 227],
];
var arr_bck = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows_bck.length; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 1; j < rows_bck[i].length; j++) {
        if (rows_bck[i][j] == null) {
            rows_bck[i][j] = 0;
            sum += rows_bck[i][j];
        } else {
        if(typeof(rows_bck[i][j]) === "number")
            sum += rows_bck[i][j];
        }
    }
    rows_bck[i].push(sum);
}
console.log(rows_bck)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const rows_bck=
[
   ["02/11", 0, 0, 0, 0],
   ["02/12", 193, 233, 212, 307],
   ["02/13", 203, 264, 293, 227]
];
const result = rows_bck.map(row => [...row, row.slice(1).reduce((sum,i)=> sum + i,0)]);
```

Explain:

1. .map(): We are mapping old rows to newer rows;
2. Spread ... operator to dump old elements in new row;
3. Use slice(1) to get all numbers by ignoring first element;
4. use reduce() to get the sum of the above numbers.